# Best graphing tool to monitor mem/cpu/traf?

Tags: ubuntu, network-monitoring, memory-usage

I am using Rackspace Cloud, oddly they don't have any way to measure your resource utilization considering it is a cloud service so I must find the best way to measure this so I can see when I should add more resources. I liked slicehost and linode's graph's, does anyone know or can recommend the best tool for the job? I am using Ubuntu if that's an consolation.

Thanks

T

Answer (score 4):

[Full Automated Nagios](http://fannagioscd.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to do this (easily); as will [icinga and icinga-web](http://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/technology-solutions/reliability-monitoring-solution/implement-icinga-on-centos6-with-selinux/).

You can monitor quite a lot for both [Nagios](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins) and [Munin](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/top), as both are very extensible.

Both Nagios and Munin use [RRDtools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) to store performance data into [RRDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-Robin_Database).

Also, just found [Cloudkick](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/tools/applications/cloud-servers-partners/system-management/cloudkick/) (and [several more SaS solutions](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/tools/category/applications/cloud-servers-partners/monitoring_and_reporting/?sort=highest_rated)) which might be a better fit for you.

I've been using the Centreon frontend to Nagios for some time, and have no complaints.  Good community and it's FOSS.

Comment: anything built around RRDTool is right for the job. For a pure graphing solution, [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net) is a popular choice.

Answer (score 1):

A popular choice for time-scaled resource graphs is [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For the quick setup and configuration, take a look at [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/).